# How to install hook procedure on external thread with custom data?

Tags: winapi

in my scenario, I have an application (that I don't own) that has multiple windows and the same thread owns the multiple windows. So that, when I install the hook procedure (from my own application, using DLL file that includes this procedure) using `SetWindowsHookEx`, it will install a hook that monitors all windows that are owned by the same thread of the target application.

What I want to achieve is that the hook procedure that is installed will have a variable called for example `targetHwnd`. Once it have it, it will ignore anything that is not `targetHwnd`.

For example, I will have something like this:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)#parameters
    if (code == HC_ACTION)
    {
        const auto msg = (MSG*)lParam;

        if (msg->hwnd != targetHwnd)
            // We skip processing any other window that owned by this thread
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);


        // Here I will do specific processing for the window I want
        // ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The question is:
How I can get to a point that the DLL with the hook procedure was injected with this external information that in our case is `targetHwnd`.

I don't see that the function `SetWindowsHookEx` has a parameter for custom data or something like that.

An alternative way I thought about is to send `WM_COPYDATA` to one of the windows that I need (and is owned by the external application thread that I installed the hook for).
Then, the `GetMsgHookProc` will get this data via the `WM_COPYDATA` message.
If in the DLL, the `targetHwnd` is `NULL`, it will take this data from the `lParam` parameter.

But then how can I tell if it was my application that sent it or it is just in case another application that also sending `WM_COPYDATA` to the window? It does not sound safe..
So I thought that I should use the `wParam` ("A handle to the window passing the data") and then verify that it was sent from my application by calling `GetClassName` and check if the class name is something unique that I expect.

But I am not sure that it is safe to use these APIs from DLL because according to MS, it may be unsafe.

So it will help me if you will give me a clue what I should do and if what I think to do is the right way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Remy Lebeau that help me to figure out the direction for the full solution. However, there are missing parts in his answer so here is the full answer I found:

The following code is copied from my app. Some parts may be missing such as methods in `Win32Native` class.

- All methods in `Win32Native` class are just collection of `DllImport` of native `Win32` APIs. So you can find it all on the pvpoke website.
- There is custom class called `WindowItem`. You will not find it anywhere.
  The only relevant information that you should know is that this class have members: `Hwnd` - The handle to the target window that we hook into, and `ProcessId` that is just the `pid` of the process that own the window. I only use these members in this code

The host app that installs the hook:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using WindowTop.Helpers;
using WindowTop.Managers;

namespace WindowTop.UI.Features.ShrinkBox
{
    public class ShrinkInteractHookNative
    {
        [DllImport("ShrinkInteractHook.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern IntPtr InstallHook(uint threadId);
    }


    public class ShrinkInteractHook : ShrinkInteractHookNative
    {
        public static IntPtr InstallHook(WindowItem windowItem)
        {
            var processId = windowItem.ProcessId;
            var windowThread = Win32Native.GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowItem.Hwnd, ref processId);
            var hHook = InstallHook(windowThread);

            var WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND = Win32Native.RegisterWindowMessage("WINDOWTOP_WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND");

            Win32Native.PostThreadMessage(windowThread, WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND, UIntPtr.Zero,
                windowItem.Hwnd);

            return hHook;
        }

        public static void UnInstallHook(IntPtr hHook)
        {
            Win32Native.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        }
    }
}
```

The `DLL`

```cpp
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"


HINSTANCE hInstHookDll = NULL;
HHOOK hHook = NULL;


HWND targetHwnd = NULL;
UINT WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND = 0;




LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgHookProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)#parameters
    if (LOWORD(msg->message) == WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND)
    {
        targetHwnd = (HWND)msg->lParam; // Here we get the targetHwnd
    }
    
    // Specific processing goes here:
    // ...
    // ...

    // Pass this to the next hook
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}


extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) HHOOK __stdcall InstallHook(unsigned int threadId)
{
    if (hHook != NULL)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
        hHook = NULL;
    }

    return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgHookProc, hInstHookDll, threadId);
}
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD reasonForCall, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (reasonForCall)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hInstHookDll = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
        WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND = RegisterWindowMessage(L"WINDOWTOP_WM_SEND_TARGET_HWND");
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // TODO: Logic in case the dll was unloaded 
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: OK, I did it now

Answer (score 2):

`WM_COPYDATA` is perfectly safe to use across thread boundaries and DLL boundaries. You can use the `COPYDATASTRUCT::dwData` field to identify whether the message belongs to you are not, simply store a unique value in that field. Typically, `RegisterWindowMessage()` is used for that purpose.

However, `WM_COPYDATA` is a bit overkill for this task. Since an `HWND` fits directly inside a `WPARAM` and `LPARAM` (as evidenced by `WM_COPYDATA`), you could just send (or even post) a custom message instead, one that only your DLL hook knows how to handle. Again, `RegisterWindowMessage()` can be used for that purpose.

Another option is to use shared memory instead, such as via `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` (or, via `#pragma data_seg`, if your compiler supports it). The app that installs the hook can allocate a block of shared memory and store the desired `HWND` in it, and then the injected DLL can access it. See [Using Shared Memory in a Dynamic-Link Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-shared-memory-in-a-dynamic-link-library).

Comment: Thanks, I also think that `WM_COPYDATA` is overkill. About `RegisterWindowMessage()` - I still have problem here. This function will return `message identifier in the range 0xC000 through 0xFFFF`. But the DLL needs to know that and it can't be known in compile time. So I end up with the almost the same question of how to send this `message identifier` to the dll

Comment: This way sounds crazy but it is very simple... I wonder if it is right: https://pastebin.com/UF30E9DR

If it is right, can I use a random number between 0 and 64 bit?

Comment: I read now the docs. I see your point about `RegisterWindowMessage()`. In docs, they said `If two different applications register the same message string, the applications return the same message value. The message remains registered until the session ends.` 
So if the DLL and the App using the same string, both should get the same message-id. 

The question is - is this is better than just using the very big magic number as I showed in https://pastebin.com/UF30E9DR ?

In the way I suggested, you use unique magic number. And in this case you use unique string for `RegisterWindowMessage()`

Comment: @gil123 yes, using `RegisterWindowMessage()` is better in this case. The OS will generate a message ID that is guaranteed to be unique and private between cooperative processes. Using a hard-coded magic number does not have that same guarantee. In your example, you are defining a private message as `WM_APP+1`. While noble, who's to say that some other process, or even the target process, isn't also using `WM_APP+1` for its own purposes? Maybe with an `lParam` that contains a value (a pointer, perhaps) that happens to randomly match your magic number? So better to let the OS handle this for you

Comment: Thanks.

I see that I was able to generate the same message-id in the DLL and in my app.
However, unfortunately - It seems that when I send a message to the DLL right after I installed it, the DLL seems to not get the message. I suspect that I am doing it too early while the DLL is still in `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` state. Is there a way to know when the DLL is loaded and only in this event I will send message to the DLL?

Comment: OK, after more debugging, I found out that the hook procedure itself is ignoring any messages that no system messages. Custom messages are not received to this hook. The OS ignoring them so it never passes them to the hook. So `RegisterWindowMessage` is not the full solution yet.

Comment: @gil123 a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook does not filter messages. Any message that is *posted* (not *sent*) to the target thread's message queue will be delivered to the hook. If your hook is not receiving the message, then either you are not *posting* the message to the target thread, or something else (maybe UIPI?) is blocking the message before it reaches the thread.

Comment: after more debugging, I found that the only thing that works well is the `PostThreadMessage()` function. This also seems to be the correct way because when I register the hook using `SetWindowsHookEx()`, I need to pass the window thread. So it seems much better to use `PostThreadMessage()` instead of `SendMessage()`. I still don't know why with `SendMessage()` I get the wrong values in the `DLL`. Maybe it is related to the fact that I am using this API from C# and the `DllImport` is wrong... But I don't think so

Comment: And it working using the message-id that generated by `RegisterWindowMessage()`

Comment: @gil123 a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook only works with *posted* messages via `PostMessage()` or `PostThreadMessage()`. For *sent* messages via `SendMessage...()`, you have to use a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook instead.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. But still, in my case, it is more straightforward to use `PostThreadMessage()` instead of `PostMessage()` because I register the hook using the thread of the window so at the same time I use the thread id to post the message